# How to add multiple elastic search data-source with different versions which are incompitable?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my spring-boot project, I use `spring-data-easticsearch 4.4.5` to connect to the `elasticsearch 8.4.3`. Now I have to connect to another very old `elasticsearch 2.4`. But according to the doc this version of spring data does not support ES 2.4. How can I connect to this new ES without altering current configuration?

Here are my configs and repos

```
public class EsConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    //
    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(esUrl)
                .usingSsl()
                .withBasicAuth(esUserName, esPassword)
                .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout))
                .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(socketTimeout))
                .build();
        return clientConfiguration;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    ///
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if ES 2.4 even already had a REST client to access it or if it was only offering the transport client. But definitely the format of data in Elasticsearch has changed (removal of types and things like that), so that this will not work with current versions anyway.

So I think you need to find some Elasticsearch specific information about migrating.

Comment: 2.1 version supports ES 2.4 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions

Comment: I know. I wrote that document. But Spring Data Elasticsearch does not support the current Elasticsearch version, it did not have any REST interface support.

Comment: wow did not see that coming